# Issue with first move of tic tac toe game

Tags: c, tic-tac-toe

this is my first post here, and would like to ask for some help with my coding project my partner and I have been working on. I'm new to programming and C in general, and am having an issue with this code we have where the first mark the first player is placing results in the mark not displaying in the console. Subsequent moves display correctly, and the program recognizes that the space is occupied as it should.

**Here is the console output displaying the issue:**

```
Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!
To make a selection, enter the row and column of the square you want to play.
Ex. 0,2 for first row, third column.


   |   |   
-----------
   |   |   
-----------
   |   |   



Player 1, choose between X or O to play: X
Do you want to start first? (Y/N): Y
Player , Where would you like to go?
Enter the row and then columns seperated by a comma here (e.g. 0,2): 1,1


   |   |   
-----------
   |  |   
-----------
   |   |   



Player X, Where would you like to go?
Enter the row and then columns seperated by a comma here (e.g. 0,2):
```

**And here is the code I'm working with:
**

```
// Tic Tac Toe game

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define PLAYER_X 'X'
#define PLAYER_O 'O'
#define OPEN ' '

// use globals for now
char player1, player2;  // player is limited to X or O
char winner = '\0';
char board[3][3] =      // board is 3 rows by 3 columns
    {
        {OPEN, OPEN, OPEN},
        {OPEN, OPEN, OPEN},
        {OPEN, OPEN, OPEN}
    };

// declare functions here

void show_directions();
void show_cat(); 
void show_winner(); 
void display_board();
char choose_player1_mark ();
bool select_first_player();
void play(char player);
bool is_winner(char player);
bool is_board_full();
char get_next_player(char current_player);


int main()
{
    char player;

    show_directions();  // welcome text hey this is tic tac toe
    display_board();
    player1 = choose_player1_mark();
    player2 = (player1 == PLAYER_X) ? PLAYER_O : PLAYER_X;
    player = select_first_player();
    
  while(!is_board_full())
    {
        play(player);
        display_board();
        if (is_winner(player))
            break;
        else
            player = get_next_player(player);
    }
  
    if (winner)
        show_winner();
    else
        show_cat();

    return 0;
}

// define functions here
void show_directions()
{
  printf("Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!\n");
  printf("To make a selection, enter the row and column of the square you want to play.\n"); 
  printf("Ex. 0,2 for first row, third column.\n");
}

void display_board()
{
  printf("\n\n");
  printf(" %c | %c | %c \n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
  printf("-----------\n");
  printf(" %c | %c | %c \n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
  printf("-----------\n");
  printf(" %c | %c | %c \n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
  printf("\n\n\n");
}

char choose_player1_mark()
{
    char choice;
    printf("Player 1, choose between X or O to play: ");
    while (1)
    {
        scanf(" %c", &choice);
        choice = toupper(choice);
        if (choice == PLAYER_X || choice == PLAYER_O)
            return choice;
        else
            printf("Invalid choice. Please enter 'X' or 'O': ");
    }
}


bool select_first_player()
{
  char choice;
  printf("Do you want to start first? (Y/N): ");
  while (1) 
  {
    scanf(" %c", &choice);
    choice = toupper(choice);
    if (choice == 'Y') 
      return true; // player 1 starts first
    else if(choice == 'N') 
      return false; // player 2 starts first
    else 
      printf("Invalid choice. Please enter 'Y' or 'N': ");
  }
}

void play(char player)
{
  int row, column;
  printf("Player %c, Where would you like to go?\n", player);
  printf("Enter the row and then columns seperated by a comma here (e.g. 0,2): ");
  scanf("%d,%d", &row, &column);
  
  while (row < 0 || row > 2 || column < 0 || column > 2 || board[row][column] != OPEN)
    {
      printf("Invalid input. Try again.\n");
      printf("Enter the row and then columns seperated by a comma here (e.g. 0,2): ");
      scanf("%d,%d", &row, &column);
    }
  
    board[row][column] = player;
}

bool is_board_full()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
          if (board[i][j] == OPEN)
          return false;
        }
    }
  return true;
}

bool is_winner(char player)
{
  // Check rows
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
      if (board[i][0] == player && board[i][1] == player && board [i][2] == player)
        {
          winner = player;
          return true;
        }
    }

  // Check columns
  for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
      if (board[0][j] == player && board[1][j] == player && board[2][j] == player)
        {
          winner = player;
          return true;
        }
    }

  // Check diagonals
  if (board[0][0] == player && board [1][1] == player && board[2][0] == player)
    {
      winner = player;
      return true;
    }

  return false;
}

char get_next_player(char current_player)
{
  return (current_player == PLAYER_X) ? PLAYER_O : PLAYER_X;
}

void show_winner()
{
  if (winner == PLAYER_X || winner == PLAYER_O)
  {
    printf("Player %c wins!\n:", winner);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("It's a tie! Cat game. \n");
  }
}

void show_cat()
{
  printf("It's a tie! Cat game.\n");
}
```

It seems that the first mark is being consumed, but I'm not sure why.
Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The condition for checking the diagonal from the top left corner to the bottom right corner is incorrect. It should be board[0][0] == player && board[1][1] == player && board[2][2] == player, but you have board[0][0] == player && board[1][1] == player && board[2][0] == player.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. This was an oversight I didn't catch.

Comment: Also, there's two diagonals.

Comment: Also true. Thank you.

Comment: `select_first_player()` returns a Boolean result, but you assign that to `PLAYER`, which is a character. - This is why your display is wrong.

Comment: `player1` and `player2` are never used once they are assigned. The only reason it works after the first turn is that `get_next_player` returns `PLAYER_X`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thank you, this was the root of the main problem I posted originally, and also another issue I uncovered too. Fixed and now the program runs as expected.

Comment: @RetiredNinja This is true. I edited the code to make this cleaner. Thanks for pointing that out.